# javascript tabbed menu shuold be selected until user move to next menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

whenever the user the tabbed menu, from then, the selected tabbed menu should be selected[in background color] until the user select next any one of the tabbed menu. each tab menu has each page on its body content.

in code, the selected tab menu should have attribute `class="selected"` inside the html until user select next equivalent menu, i need this in javascript or in jquery.

Any help? please

my html code for this

```
<ul class="mainnav" id="mainnav1">
<li><a href=""><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>Test orders</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>Access arrangements</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>Pupil registration</span></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="active"><span>Teacher assessment</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>Pupil results</span></a></li>
<li><a href=""><span>Phonics screening check</span></a></li></ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Check out `$.removeClass()` and `$.addClass()` in jQuery.

Comment: for tabbed menu what jquery you are using

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can help.

```
$("#mainnav1 li a").on("click", function(){
    $("#mainnav1 li a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    return false;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcfwtqzo/)

Comment: will this be active until next menu be clicked? what will happen if user click the body content of this page? pls

Comment: Feel free to try it out. It will remain active wherever user decide to click.

Comment: hi, this is not working on my aspx generated html page. Any clue?

Comment: Try adding this code to document ready event Ex. `$(function() {
//place code here
});`

Comment: i included the code between this $ (document).ready(function () { }); Is this okay? if this ok, then, it is not working for mr as of now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59216/discussion-between-sakthivel-and-dexa).